# Sort result by a date range SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table data like below. There are 3 columns: `ID`, `date1` and `date2`:

```
01 | 2020-01-01  | 2020-01-28 
02 | 2020-01-05  | 2020-01-15 
03 | 2020-01-05  | 2020-01-23
```

I want to sort them like this

```
03 | 2020-01-05  | 2020-01-23
01 | 2020-01-05  | 2020-01-15 
02 | 2020-01-01  | 2020-01-28
```

Latest date first in both date columns. Which means I have to order by both dates. I tried this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM schema.TESTTABLE 
ORDER BY date1, date2 DESC
```

This query returns data set like this:

```
02 | 2020-01-01  | 2020-01-28 
03 | 2020-01-05  | 2020-01-23 
01 | 2020-01-05  | 2020-01-15
```

`date1` is not sorted as I expected. Any suggestions..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DId you try:

```
SELECT * FROM schema.TESTTABLE ORDER BY date1 desc,date2 desc
```

Answer (score 2):

Default is `asc`, So you need to address `desc` for `date1` like this

```
 SELECT * FROM schema.TESTTABLE ORDER BY date1 desc,date2 desc
```

> The ORDER BY keyword sorts the records in **ascending order by default**.
>   To sort the records in descending order, use the **DESC** keyword.

More details in https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp